# ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature' from 'setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I want to install the requirements of this https://github.com/sraashis/deepdyn project, but when I run:

```
pip install -r deepdyn/assets/requirements.txt
```

I receive the following error in the terminal:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/masoud/anaconda3/envs/tfgpu/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xzvdvhgj/MarkupSafe/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xzvdvhgj/MarkupSafe/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v7ebj7ab
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xzvdvhgj/MarkupSafe/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-xzvdvhgj/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature' from 'setuptools' (/home/masoud/anaconda3/envs/tfgpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: That's a problem from upstream. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2017

Comment: Here's the specific package the dependency issue is https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/issues/116

Comment: Try ==> pip install --upgrade pip setuptools==44.1.0 This is documented as an issue here https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2017

Comment: Here's the command I had to use to resolve this `pip3 install setuptools==45`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug was fixed in [version 1.1](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/commit/fe626819d10e063270bf0ed3b183249482b1a0e7#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298L6) but `deepdyn` [requires](https://github.com/sraashis/deepdyn/blob/25e4d87b55694a32fe72cbfabc9e876a6573c28a/assets/requirements.txt#L16) version 1.0. This is probably a bug in `deepdyn` and should be [reported](https://github.com/sraashis/deepdyn/issues).

Or may be `deepdyn` requires some older version of `setuptools`. Again, ask the authors about it.

Comment: Here's the command I had to use to resolve this
`pip3 install setuptools==45`